# mssql charindex how to change limitation for expressionToSearch

Tags: sql-server-2008, charindex

In table1 exists raw with column field1='1234'.
When length of expressionToSearch is greater than 4000 symbols
then the following query in MSSQL 2008 EXPRESS Edition

```
select field1,Charindex(field1,expressionToSearch+'1234') AS cindex from table1
where field1='1234'
```

returns

```
field1    cindex
1234        0
```

how we can change the limitation or how we can find the index of the field in expressionToSearch without using charindex ?

Answer (score 0):

If the length of expressionToSearch is greater than 4000 then it should be converted to Nvarchar(max)

```
Charindex(field1,CAST(expressionToSearch AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```